# QML MediaPlayer on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qml, multimedia

Has anyone tried to play movie link (MP4) using QML MediaPlayer on Ubuntu Touch?

Currently I can only get audio but without any video.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I usualy use MP4 as prefered format on Ubuntu Touch no problem. It's very basic video player many things are unsupported. I suspect that you are using unsupported codec for example h.265 or other fancy codecs. Try converting it to h.264 (working for sure).